# Could not find implicit value for ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm just starting out with Akka and Scala and I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket using Akka Streams. I've created my `SocketActor` below and I try to instantiate from the main method.

Here is my `SocketActor`:

```
package com.lightbend.akka.sample

import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import akka.Done
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._
import scala.concurrent.Future


object SocketActor {

  def props(coinApiIdentifier: String): Props = Props(new SocketActor(coinApiIdentifier))

  case object Start

  case object Stop

}

class SocketActor(val ticker: String) extends Actor {

  import SocketActor._


  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes
  private val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println(message.text)
  }

  // send this as a message over the WebSocket
  private val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

  // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
  private val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("wss://api.com/v1/"))

  // the materialized value is a tuple with
  // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
  // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
  // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
  private val graph =
  outgoing
    .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]


  override def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case Start =>
      println("Start message received.")
      graph.run()
  }
}
```

And my main method:

```
object AkkaQuickstart extends App {

  // Create the 'helloAkka' actor system
  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
  val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val socketActor: ActorRef =
    system.actorOf(SocketActor.props("hello"), "socket-actor")

  socketActor ! Start
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> Error:(38, 35) could not find implicit value for parameter system:
>   akka.actor.ActorSystem   private val webSocketFlow =
>   Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("wss://api.com/v1/"))

I've tried passing some `implicit` parameters to the constructor of the `SocketActor` but that didn't work too well. It seems like the `ActorSystem` is not in scope for some reason. How can I get my `system` in scope for the `Http()` function in `SocketActor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define an implicit `val`:

```
class SocketActor(val ticker: String) extends Actor {
  implicit val sys = context.system
  // ...
}
```

This will provide the implicit `ActorSystem` that the `Http` object expects.

There is another issue with your code: the stream in your actor will not run because there is no materializer in scope. One way to address this is to create the materializer inside the actor:

```
class SocketActor(val ticker: String) extends Actor {
  implicit val sys = context.system
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()(context)
  // ...
}
```

Note that if the materializer were defined as `implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()`, it would implicitly use `context.system` because of the `implicit val sys = context.system`. Instead, the materializer is created with the actor's `context` explicitly. This is done because of the warning in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#actor-materializer-lifecycle):

> Do not create new actor materializers inside actors by passing the `context.system` to it. This will cause a new `ActorMaterializer` to be created and potentially leaked (unless you shut it down explicitly) for each such actor. It is instead recommended to either pass-in the Materializer or create one using the actor’s `context`.

The recommended approach, which allows the creator of the actor to reuse a materializer, is to pass the materializer to the actor as an implicit parameter:

```
class SocketActor(val ticker: String)(implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer) extends Actor {
  implicit val sys = context.system
  // ...
}
```

Then you could pass the materializer in the main program to this actor:

```
object AkkaQuickstart extends App {

  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val socketActor: ActorRef =
    system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SocketActor], "hello", materializer), "socket-actor")

  socketActor ! Start
}
```